# Difference between APIController and MVCController?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, api, model-view-controller

I'm studiyng API Rest and when I create a controller I have a lot of options.
But I want to understand technically the difference between 'APIController with read/write options' and 'MVCController with read/write options'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjsxn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An API controller returns messages (or data), a MVC one returns views and data at once.

See [this](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/webapi/difference-between-aspnet-mvc-and-aspnet-web-api) for more information.

The API controller is best used in a REST context, as in, it's used to build a REST service, independent from any front-end representation.

The MVC controller is inherently designed for a MVC context, and as such returns views (and the required data) to be displayed by the web application.